# Error using round command and how to export a .csv table in NetLogo 6.2

Tags: netlogo

I've been trying since yesterday to code the following:

```
to output
  file-open ( word NameOutfile-output ".csv" )
  ifelse Integer? = true ; interger switch in GUI
    [file-print ( word "id;my_xcor;my_ycor" ) file-print ( word self " ; " round my-xcor " ; " round my-yco )]
    [file-print ( word "id;my_xcor;my_ycor" ) file-print ( word self " ; " my-xcor " ; " my-ycor )]
  file-close
end
```

1. I have non-integer coordinate values. I would like to put a switch on the interface if it is turned on it will generate an output with integer values. But, it is giving the following error: ROUND expected input to be a number but got the list [1 2 1 1 1] instead.
2. I don't know how to close a created .csv file. For example: I export a .csv table. If I run it again, the model will save the results in the table already created. I wish that didn't happen. It is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As you said, NetLogo tells you that `round` wants a number as input but you're giving it a list.

You can fix this by using [map](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map), which lets you run reporters on all elements of a list (and [round](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#round) is a reporter indeed):

```
to round-my-list
  let my-list [3.1 5.6 8.32]
  let my-list-rounded (map round my-list)
  print my-list-rounded
end
```

2. What you are experiencing with the file is the standard behaviour. From the NetLogo Dictionary at `file-open`, you can [read this](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#file-open):

> When opening a file in writing mode, all new data will be appended to the end of the original file. [...] If you don't want to append, but want to replace the file's existing contents, use file-delete to delete it first, perhaps inside a carefully if you're not sure whether it already exists.

So if you want every time a new file, you should add something to your code that first tells to delete that file; then, write it again. Using `file-delete` and `carefully` in combination as suggested in the NetLogo Dictionary:

```
to output

  carefully
    [file-delete ( word NameOutfile-output ".csv" )]
    []

  file-open ( word NameOutfile-output ".csv" )
  ifelse Integer? = true ; interger switch in GUI
    [file-print ( word "id;my_xcor;my_ycor" ) file-print ( word self " ; " round my-xcor " ; " round my-yco )]
    [file-print ( word "id;my_xcor;my_ycor" ) file-print ( word self " ; " my-xcor " ; " my-ycor )]
  file-close
end
```